# Vulnerable Javascript library jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss, opencart

i have a report from acunetix with this results:

> Description
>   You are using a vulnerable Javascript library. One or more vulnerabilities were reported for this version of the Javascript library. Consult Attack details and Web References for more information about the affected library and the vulnerabilities that were reported.
>   Consult Web References for more information.
>   Recommendation
>   Upgrade to the latest version.

I have found the patch file
https://gist.github.com/jzaefferer/f945add6e6d32935d906
How i can patch the file?
Thank you!

Comment: Just upgrade to the latest version of jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux based OS, you can type on a terminal:

```
patch -u jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js dialog-6016.patch
```

Comment: patching file jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
Hunk #1 FAILED at 347.
patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
Hunk #2 FAILED at 612.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js.rej

Comment: It seems that the patch is for https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js?r=3474 and not for jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js